# find a string and extract next 10 characters adjacent to it in R or python

Tags: python, nlp

Say i have

> item : 0123456789

I need to find "item" word in the text document and store "0123456789" into some variable
is there a way to do it in R or Python

Comment: in Python use `split(' : ')`

Comment: Yes, use regular expressions.

Comment: [have a look](https://regex101.com/r/uu9A4f/1)

Comment: tag spamming is frowned upon, esp when you're asking contributors for a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """Hello World
item : 0123456789
Hello World
"""

m = re.search(r"item : (\d*)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
0123456789
```